# I am using Ubuntu (and Chrome) in dark mode, but I would like the websites I visit to always use light mode be default. Is this doable?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I am using Ubuntu in dark mode and Chrome is also in dark mode because it takes the mode from the OS. I would like the websites I visit to always use light mode be default.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Websites can use the "prefers-color-scheme" property to adapt their styles based on whether the user's browser theme prefers light mode or dark mode.

Chrome doesn't provide any user-adjustable options that let you alter this other than within Developer Tools, there is a feature that lets you toggle this to test how your site reacts.

If you're interested in that, open devtools (F12). Inside the "Styles" pane, next to the "+" button, click the Icon "Toggle common rendering emulations" and you will see a "prefers-color-scheme" toggle.

Otherwise, maybe it is possible to manipulate this by using custom Chrome themes.  Maybe there is such a thing as a theme that looks dark but doesn't register as dark mode.